# Use of foreign_key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When,why and how do we use foreign_key in rails?
And what is the difference between primary key and foreign key?
I'm kinda new in rails so a detailed explanation would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the Rails Guides about this? :) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

You use `foreign_key` in associations, when foreign key name can't be inferred from the name of association. For example, if you have `users` and `groups` tables in database:

```
users
  -id
  -name
  -group_id
groups
  -id
  -name
```

You can set association between `User` and `Group` without specifying foreign key:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

But if you had, for example, `groupid` instead of `group_id` in `users` table, you would have to do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group, foreign_key: :groupid
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, foreign_key: :groupid
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Primary and foreign keys are concepts from database design. If you want to properly understand them I recommend stepping away from Rails for a minute and look at them as they are applied directly to a database. See for instance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key